# Добрый день, не могу решить задачу Максимальная прибыль

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, математика

Задача была изначально на англ. перевел и успел только заскринить. Подскажите путь для решения или тип задачи чтобы я мог порешать подобные задачи
[image: первая часть]
[image: вторая часть]

Comment: Очень похоже на задачу по динамическому программированию

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: С чем именно у вас возникли проблемы? Если вы хотите решать подобные задачи, то тогда начните учить язык, есть много учебников, статей и видеоуроков, начните их просматривать, тут место где помогают вам решить задачи, а не решают их за вас. Как только вы покажите ваши попытки решить задачу, вам укажут что вы сделали не так и помогут.

Comment: у меня возникли проблемы с пониманием задачи, почему просто не перемножить категорию на цену? в сумме выйдет тоже самое

Comment: А можно источник где можно почитать и посмотреть решения подобных задач?

Comment: @Danik Kazakhstan Это случайно совпало, в верхнем примере же не так.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуем так -

1. выгоднее сначала дешёвые продавать, потом, когда категорий станет больше, продавать дорогие - это очевидно
2. выгоднее сначала продать по одному предмету из каждой категории, чтобы  следующие предметы из этой категории шли по максимальной цене - а вот мне это не вполне очевидно, как строго обосновать, однако проверка на случайных данных работает

Таким образом, выбираем из каждой категории минимальный элемент, сортируем их по возрастанию, считаем выгоду в этом порядке, потом добавляем сумму оставшихся цен, умноженную на количество категорий

```
[8, 13, 9, 20, 5, 3, 8, 15]    price
[6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 6, 1, 5]       category

 тупой метод, перебирающий все перестановки (выгода, последовательность для лучшей выгоды) 
297 [5, 4, 6, 1, 0, 2, 3, 7]  
  описанный алгоритм 
297
```

Comment: @Danik Kazakhstan Ну что, разобрались?